# MissingMethodException on Unity Based Dependency Resolution in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, unity-container

On running a Xamarin Android application in debug mode, I am getting the below error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: bool
System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.TryPop(!0&)
```

And it is happening at the below call in the application for the Unity based dependency injection code:

```
this.Container.Resolve<T>();
```

There is no more stack trace data is also coming out for this issue.

Surprising thing is that the same project is working fine in `VS 2017 (15.7.4)` and not in a machine I have with `VS 2017 (15.8.8)`.

Any possible solutions or leads for solving this will be helpful.

**UPDATE:**

I just downgraded my `VS 2017` to `15.7.6` now and I am getting the same error still with that too.

**WORK AROUND**:

Once I changed targeted Android version of my Xamarin Android `csproj` in the Application Manifest to 5.1, I am able to get through my app in debug bypassing this issue. But, not sure what exactly solved by that. But, still it does not work in any targeted version above 5.1.

It will be great if a permanent solution can be identified for this issue even in higher Android target versions.

Comment: Assuming you are using `Xamarin.Android` 7.1 or greater? What Xamarin.Android version is installed?

Comment: @SushiHangover, `Xamarin.Android` is of version 9.0.0.19 and `Xamarin` is of version 4.11.0.776

Comment: check if the T in this.Container.Resolve<T>(); is registered using container.RegisterType<T, TImplementation>();

Comment: Registrations are available for all the types which are getting resolved by using T